# Newtonsoft Json - Serialize Deep nested object based on given selected properties

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, datacontractserializer

Does Newtonsoft Json have any way to serialize nested objects with only selected properties ?
The model looks like:

```
class Node
{
int id{ get; set; };
string name{ get; set; };
IList<Node>children{ get; set; };
}
```

I am creating a tree structure afterwards which looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "D",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Wrote my own serializer. I passed Children property only .It shows as:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show all properties and not just children under 1st/root's children.Similar to below.

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "D",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

Also how do I do the same for children.Id where I want to serialize all children.Id of root node,Similar to below

```
{
"children": [
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

they have done the same result you want to achieve on this page.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing

Also, see Here,

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/58283745/self-reference-when-serializing-nested-object

I hope that will be useful.

Comment: JObject creation and looping through all the data and populating them in JObject seems to be a performance issue to me for huge data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need your own serializer for? Try the standard one

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(json);
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDeserialized);
```

Output

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "children": null
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "C",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "D",
          "children": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Classes

```
public partial class Child
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

For this

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "D",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

You can use

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if I dont want children to be included now,I want some other property maybe XYZ for another model.Do I create these partial class for each of them? What if I want Children.Children ?

Comment: @netcoredev "What if I want" -  you have to decide what you want  and only after this  to ask how to reach it. You need a class for each  if you want or a JToken at least.

Comment: Will try JToken way.Thanks